# Conjure-up --bootstrap-to fails

Tags: juju, maas, landscape

This problem is similar to: [JUJU bootstrap stucks Fetching Juju Agent version 2.0.2 for amd64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862995/juju-bootstrap-stucks-fetching-juju-agent-version-2-0-2-for-amd64)

I am following the instructions on: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot

I am trying to run Autopilot in order to deploy openstack. My MAAS server is running, and I have 5 nodes commmissioned. I am running conjure-up from my MAAS controller.

When I run conjure-up --bootstrap-to {MAAS commissioned node in READY state}, I select landscape, and then select maas as my cloud type, enter credentials and endpoint. Conjure-up proceeds and deploys the node successfully.

Conjure-up hangs at this point. Here is the output of conjure-up.....bootstrap.err:

```
Creating Juju controller "conjure-up-cloud-maas-0d1-93a" on cloud-maas-0d1
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.2 for amd64  
Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-maas-0d1...
 - te3f68 (arch=amd64 mem=32G cores=8)   
Fetching Juju GUI 2.7.5  
Attempting to connect to 192.168.2.15:22  
sudo: unable to resolve host quiet-boa: Connection timed out*

**Following is from my MAAS server**:  
$ which juju  
/snap/bin/juju  
$ which conjure-up  
/snap/bin/conjure-up  
$ which lxd  
/usr/bin/lxd  
$ juju version  
2.2.2-xenial-amd64  
$ conjure-up --version  
conjure-up 2.2.2  
$ lxd --version  
2.0.10  
$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

**Here is output of conjure-up.log**

```
2017-07-31 10:43:31,964 [INFO] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - events.py:178 - Watching for shutdown
2017-07-31 10:43:32,011 [DEBUG] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - events.py:55 - Awaiting Shutdown at conjureup/events.py:180
2017-07-31 10:43:37,404 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - download.py:60 - Path is local filesystem, copying /snap/conjure-up/561/spells/landscape to /home/ernie/.cache/conjure-up/landscape
2017-07-31 10:43:37,410 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - utils.py:392 - Pulling bundle for landscape-dense-maas from channel: stable
2017-07-31 10:46:11,237 [INFO] conjure-up/landscape - common.py:77 - Bootstrapping Juju controller.
2017-07-31 10:46:11,238 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:170 - bootstrap cmd: ['juju', 'bootstrap', 'cloud-maas-0d1', 'conjure-up-cloud-maas-0d1-93a', '--default-model', 'conjure-landscape-1b1', '--config', 'image-stream=daily', '--config', 'enable-os-upgrade=false', '--to', 'trusty-cicada', '--bootstrap-series', 'xenial', '--credential', 'conjure-cloud-maas-0d1-fee']
2017-07-31 10:46:11,257 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting ModelConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/common.py:23
2017-07-31 10:46:11,261 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:179 - waiting for proc
2017-07-31 10:46:11,471 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - maas.py:401 - Found endpoint: http://maas:5240/MAAS for cloud: cloud-maas-0d1
2017-07-31 10:46:11,472 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Setting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:285
2017-07-31 10:46:36,934 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - gui.py:13 - Rendering bootstrap wait
2017-07-31 10:46:37,034 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,035 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,036 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,130 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,131 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,132 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,226 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,227 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,228 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,322 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,323 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,324 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-31 10:46:37,330 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting Bootstrapped at conjureup/controllers/bootstrapwait/gui.py:37
2017-07-31 10:46:37,336 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:landscape-server at /snap/conjure-up/561/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-31 10:46:37,338 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:rabbitmq-server at /snap/conjure-up/561/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-31 10:46:37,340 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:postgresql at /snap/conjure-up/561/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-31 10:46:37,341 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:haproxy at /snap/conjure-up/561/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-31 11:01:00,945 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:181 - proc done
2017-07-31 11:01:00,945 [ERROR] conjure-up/landscape - common.py:36 - Error bootstrapping controller: ['Creating Juju controller "conjure-up-cloud-maas-0d1-93a" on cloud-maas-0d1', 'Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.2 for amd64', 'Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-maas-0d1...', ' - te3f68 (arch=amd64 mem=32G cores=8) ', 'Fetching Juju GUI 2.7.5', 'Waiting for address', 'Attempting to connect to 192.168.2.17:22', 'sudo: unable to resolve host trusty-cicada: Connection timed out', 'Connection to 192.168.2.17 closed by remote host.', 'ERROR failed to bootstrap model: subprocess encountered error code 255']
2017-07-31 11:01:00,947 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Setting Error at conjureup/events.py:147
2017-07-31 11:01:01,028 [ERROR] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:166 - Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/561/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/bootstrap/common.py", line 39, in do_bootstrap
    app.current_cloud_type))
Exception: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: maas)
2017-07-31 11:01:01,033 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - __init__.py:21 - Showing dialog for exception: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: maas)
```

Comment: This shows failing to connect to that node, are you running this on a private network where only a single dhcp server exist?

Comment: Yes, I found the issue. The DNS server for the VLAN wasnt configured properly. I used the MAAS servers IP address and that got me past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the Submitter, the issue was a DNS misconfiguration.

> Yes, I found the issue. The DNS server for the VLAN wasnt configured
>   properly. I used the MAAS servers IP address and that got me past this
>   issue. – Ernest Martinez Jul 31 '17 at 16:46